# VaryByCustom - Data being shown to wrong users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I'm using Windows Auth in an Intranet setting to Cache information pulled from Active Directory. The purpose of the Cache is to speed up the page, as reading from AD is not particularly fast, and doesn't need to be done every single time. (The data doesn't change all that often)

To do this, i'm setting a custom key in HttpContext.Application.

This is the code located in Global.asax to handle VaryByCustom:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("GetVaryByCustomString : " + context.Application["BrowsingSession_Key"].ToString());
            if (arg == "BrowsingSession_Key")
            {
                object o = context.Application["BrowsingSession_Key"];
                if (o == null)
                {
                    o = Guid.NewGuid();
                    context.Application["BrowsingSession_Key"] = o;
                }
                return o.ToString();
            }
            return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
        }
```

In my BaseController (Inherited by all my controllers):

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(requestContext);
            //Custom Cache Initiation Variable
            if (HttpContext.Application["BrowsingSession_Key"] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Application["BrowsingSession_Key"] = Guid.NewGuid();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("BaseController.Initialize : " + HttpContext.Application["BrowsingSession_Key"].ToString());
            }
        }
```

And finally, in my method inside a controller:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 300, VaryByCustom = "BrowsingSession_Key", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
        public ActionResult Index(HomeViewModel model)
//...
        return View("index", model);
    }
```

The issue is simple - the first person to view the page has their info cached, and the Guid for BrowsingSession_Key is set.
However, the next user visits the page within the 5 minute window, and reaches the last users cached content.
As you can see - i'm attempting to give each user a unique BrowsingSession_Key, so that they get their own cached content.

I'm using VaryByCustom so that i can quickly invalidate the cache by assigning a new BrowsingSession_Key (Guid) to that user - and pull a non-cached copy of a page for them.

Can you see what's going wrong here?
From my testing - it seems Initialize is often called, as is GetVaryByCustomString, in the places you'd expect them to be called. However, i can't run debug as multiple users, so i can't see why they're getting the same Guid and the same outputcache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, Application-level variables are not a good place to be storing per-user information, even temporarily.

In the end, i swapped over to using a cookie with a stored GUID, and invalidate the cookie (reset the GUID, or delete & Re-create). This meant multiple users were then able to use the site, with GetVaryByCustomString instead handling information stored in the Cookie.

This works for me - but i need to take into account the possibility of users swapping cookies, so will look further into encryption options.
For now - the answer is - Don't use Application-level variables this way, they're not suited to such tasks.